# Understanding Brown tags

Tags: syntax, nlp, part-of-speech

I was reading about linguistics in relation to Natural Language Processing, but the Brown tags are confusing me.

Can you help me explaining the following tags (if you can add an example, much better)? All of them are related to [interrogative pronouns and interrogative determiners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogative_pronoun).

1. WDT (wh-determiner: what, which)
2. WP$ (possessive wh-pronoun: whose)
3. WPO (objective wh-pronoun: whom, which, that)
4. WPS (nominative wh-pronoun: who, which, that)

For example, a determiner should be **the** in **The dog** because as it's defined, it describes the reference of a noun in a context. But what about a wh-determiner? What purpose does it serve? Asking about the reference of a noun or in which way should I interpret these forms?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try asking this on http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Actually, there are more nlp tags here than in linguistics.se

Comment: That's because SO is much bigger: 3.5 million questions versus 660 questions.  Yours could be one of them.  I would also consider syntax, parts-of-speech, and computational-linguistics as potential tags for this question.

Comment: Right. But then do you recommend me to ask this question in linguistics.se? It seems I have better chances of getting an answer here because of the sheer amount of participants.

Comment: The number of answerers is much higher, but so is the number of questions.  Supposing number of people browsing questions to answer is proportional to the number of questions, it comes down to which forum's users are more likely to be able to answer your question, and I think you are much more likely to find people who can answer questions about part of speech tags on the linguistics forum.  Just trying to help.

Comment: Great. Can you migrate it or do I need to do it manually?

Comment: I have never migrated, but I think it only works across certain sites.  I would just create it manually over there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can help you out on the wh-determiner.  It's just a wh-word (specifically, 'what' or 'which') in the place of an ordinary determiner.  It replaces the 'the' and in so doing shows that the speaker is unclear about which or what noun is verbing.  For example:

(1) I milked the cow yesterday.

(2) Which cow did you milk yesterday?

See how the 'which' replaces the 'the'?  It's even clearer in the form of an echo question:

(3) You milked *which* cow yesterday?

Similarly, the possessive wh-pronoun takes the place of 'his', 'her', 'their', 'our' etc. in a question.

(4) Whose cow did you milk yesterday?

(5) I milked his cow yesterday.

The objective and nominative wh-pronouns, meanwhile, are 'true' pronouns, in that they help replace a noun phrase in its entirety.

(6) Whom did you milk?

(7) Who milked the cow?

Hope this helps :)